# Adding RGB values to ply file

Tags: 3d, rgb, point-cloud-library, lidar-data

I have a .ply file of lidar point-cloud that looks like below:

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex 80000
property float32 x
property float32 y
property float32 z
end_header
18.8456 8.7657 -8.2815 
19.5461 9.5788 -6.7331 
19.5461 9.9162 -5.4418 
19.5461 10.1308 -4.6204 
19.5461 10.2636 -4.1129 
19.5461 10.3629 -3.7334 
19.5461 10.4289 -3.4809 
19.5461 10.4620 -3.3544
```

This file is generated automatically by the tool. How can I convert this file to .pts format:
[image]

I have already gone through [Adding color to vertex points in ply format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122934/adding-color-to-vertex-points-in-ply-format). It is providing the structure of .ply file but not any method to fill RGB values

Comment: Your .ply file seems to contains only x, y, z values. You will not be able de read color information nor Scalar information from it.

Comment: I have intensity value in Watts. Is there a way I can map it to scalar? Also would it help if I use as given here? [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#Specification_of_the_transformation]

Comment: Mapping a scalar to RGB color is usually done with LookUp tables. For example, VTK provides this feature (https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkLookupTable.html#details). A simple solution could be: normalize your Watts values between 0 and 255 and assign it to red, green and blue. This will gives you a mapping to greyscale.